# hyphenate only when the word is too long for one whole sentence

Tags: javascript, css, string

There are already many questions about hyphenating words, but I couldn't find a question about hyphenate only when one word that is **by it's own** too long for one whole sentence.

example:

I like this to be intact (not trying to put the word "verlichtingssysteem" in the upper line with hyphenates)

[image]

So I don't want this:

[image]

But I want to have a word that doesn't fit the whole line/div/page is hyphenated. Otherwise I can't see the text in full as you can see below. (it cuts off the last 3 characters)

[image]

All the solutions I have seen before on other questions does hyphenate on both last 2 examples instead of only the last example.

So it needs only to hyphenate when a word **by it's own width** doesn't fit the whole div/page, so when you have two words it just needs to place the word on the next line instead of hyphenating.

I only have this word fall off screen problem on mobile. But an (soft) hyphenate messes up on other devices that have a bigger width as you can see on picture 2. So I only need it for one word that **by it's own** to big on one line.

I don't think I am the only one who has this desire?

Comment: see https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/

Comment: The hyphenate trick doesn't do the trick in this situation, I have edited the question much to clarify the problem, I hope it helps

Comment: There is a similar question but no good solution so this may be impossible to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209503/show-hyphens-only-when-necessary-soft-hyphens-doesnt-cut-it

Answer (score 2):

you can use `&shy;`

It only breaks a word when it would overlap the content width.

use it like `this&shy;text&shy;is&shy;getting&shy;long` = this­text­is­getting­long

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2r70mhnw/1/

you probably have to set the width of the container to 100%, that's all!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen

> In computing and typesetting, a soft hyphen (ISO 8859: 0xAD, Unicode U+00AD soft hyphen, HTML: ­ ­) or syllable hyphen (EBCDIC: 0xCA), abbreviated SHY, is a code point reserved in some coded character sets for the purpose of breaking words across lines by inserting visible hyphens.

Comment: I have edited my question for clarification. If I do &shy; in "verlichtingssysteem" like "Verlichtings&shy;systeem and I have a window that gives more width. You get the same problem as the second picture.

He tries to cut the long word with the soft hyphen to fit it on the first sentence while I want the browser only doing it when one word that is to long on the whole width is hyphenated.

Comment: added a fiddle. you probably have to set a width of 100% to the container

Comment: But the width has the same length as the container. I only have this word fall off screen problem on mobile. But an (soft) hyphenate messes up on other devices that has a width size that is enough to have the word in full. Because then I have the problem like the second picture.

Comment: well another option would be to use a `<br>` tag which has `display: none` in `@media all and (min-width: 420px)` (or whatever size your mobile query has). and `content: "-"` in your mobile query.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases using

```
/* using those two for compatibility reasons with old browsers */
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

could be a valid solution. Beside its probably not a good solution for text content, I found it really useful to use e.g. in navigations or titles.

It breaks only single words if this particular word does not fit into the line. While it does not add "-" and does no real hyphenation, though.